# Anuglar 4 - selected for select with enum not working

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have the following enum:

```
export enum Category {
  SYSTEM = 0,
  NAVIGATION = 1,
  MESSAGING = 2,
  MEDIA = 3
}
```

and a mapping to labels via:

```
export const CategoryMapping = [
    { value: Category.SYSTEM, label: 'System' },
    { value: Category.NAVIGATION, label: 'Navigation'},
    { value: Category.MESSAGING, label: 'Messaging'},
    { value: Category.MEDIA, label: 'Media'}
];
```

I also have an object that has the category as its field.

My goal is to display the categories in a select, bind it to the object's category field and display the current value by default when displaying:

```
<select class="form-control" id="category" [(ngModel)]="myObj.category">
      <option
        *ngFor="let category of categories"
        [ngValue]="category.value"
        [selected]="category.value == myObj.category">
          {{ category.label }}
      </option>
    </select>
```

The `categories` I'm referring to is the mapping.

However, no value is selected by default. I know that the ngModel and the ngValue types have to be the same, but an enum implicitly is an integer, so I figured it works. Also the selected expression results to true for the matching category, but it's still not selected by default.

Answer (score 2):

By default when you try to use `enum` value, they return their current index. I think you're assuming to get `string` value that you have written for enum.

You have to tweak a `enum` a bit, like instead of getting using enum value like `Category.SYSTEM` to `Category[Category.SYSTEM]` which will return a `string`.

```
export const [
    { value: Category[Category.SYSTEM], label: 'System' },
    { value: Category[Category.NAVIGATION], label: 'Navigation' },
    { value: Category[Category.MESSAGING], label: 'Messaging' },
    { value: Category[Category.MEDIA], label: 'Media' }
];
```

[**Demo Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aeadgz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)